# when a lightbox form (using colorbox) closes refresh the page that was behind it

Tags: javascript, colorbox

So what I am trying to achieve is when the lightbox (using colorbox) closes the page that was behind it refreshes. (so the php variables will update)

```
  <script>
if(parent.jQuery.colorbox.close()){
window.refresh(); 
   }
  </script>
```

Currently the lightbox closes but the page doesn't reload so the variables don't update :(

any help would be great:) thank you in advance!

Requested extra Code:)

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('a.out').colorbox({iframe:true,opacity:0.5,scrolling:false,width:"400px",height:"300px",transition:"none"});
              onClosed: function() { location.reload(true); }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because window has no method refresh. Use `location.reload(true);` instead.

### Edit: new code after comment on 2014-02-18 13:40

This code would do the trick:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.out').colorbox({
            iframe: true,
            opacity: 0.5,
            scrolling: false,
            width: '400px',
            height: '300px',
            transition: 'none',
            onClosed: function() {
                location.reload(true);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. unfortunately no luck. nothing seemed to change.

Comment: Then that line isn't executed because colorbox is already closed and that piece of JavaScript is deleted. Try to put that line in the onClosed event of colorbox where you initialize your colorbox. Like this: `onClosed: function() { location.reload(true); }`

Comment: Hello, That function seems to stop the pop box from appearing it just moves the user to a new page. Any suggestions? Thank you:)

Comment: Did you test it? According to the Colorbox documentation, the onClosed event is executed when Colorbox has completed it's closing function. If you've tested it and your box isn't showing at all, you probably have an error in your initializing code. Can you post the code where you initialize your Colorbox?

Comment: I just added an example that should work. I also replaced jQuery with $, since that's shorter but does the same :)